# Accessing EC2 metadata service from CodeBuild instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker

I'm running a docker container from within AWS CodeBuild inside my VPC.  On the host, I have no problem running `aws sts get-caller-identity` with no credentials.  E.g.:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "[redacted]",
    "Account": "[redacted]",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::[redacted]:assumed-role/[redacted]"
}
```

Inside the docker container however, I get an error trying to get my identity:

```
% aws sts get-caller-identity
Couldn't reach EC2 metadata service.

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

I assume this is because I can't reach the EC2 metadata service to obtain the role keys, but I thought that should "just work" since the container should have access to the same network as the host.

So I backed out and took another look at the host - it looks like I can't access the metadata service on http://169.254.169.254:

```
# curl -kv http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
*   Trying 169.254.169.254:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 169.254.169.254: Invalid argument
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

How is `aws sts` working on the host?  I thought the AWS CLI needed access to that metadata service if credentials weren't supplied.  How can I get it working inside the container (I don't want to pass long lived tokens around in environment variables)?

(edited with additional detail found from exploring directly on SessionManager in the CodeBuild instance)

Comment: CodeBuild builds in containers, not on EC2, though I guess ultimately the containers are on EC2. I guess there's no way to get the instance metadata. Same thing happens on RDS / Oracle, you can't access the instance role. One workaround is to pass in credentials in a parameter.

Comment: Problem there is I actually would need credentials - including managing them, rotating them, passing them around as env vars, etc.  The point of instance roles is that I can just say "This CodeBuild project should have these permissions" and I'm done.  And this works on the CodeBuild instance, just not inside the docker container spawned on that instance - and I'm not sure how that is - doesn't seem to follow how the AWS CLI is documented.  If that is how it is though, how can I get the credentials from the role to pass them to the container?

Answer (score 3):

Best I've found for this so far...

Thanks for the comment from @Tim, CodeBuild runs on ECS.  When it does that, it pulls credentials from container credentials.  Those are apparently pulled from a different IP address, which can be accessed via

`169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`

You can extract the role credentials from that call and then pass them into the Docker container.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if RDS is similar. If it did that could've said us a LOT of time.